# Dynamic expanding visual basic forms

Tags: forms, dynamic, basic

I have what is most likely a simple question.  I have a visual basic form but when I expand it none of the fields or text expands with the window.  I was wondering how to make it so the form dynamically expands when someone maximizes or expands the window on the desktop  Could someone please advise thank you!

Comment: Can you post any methods/code you've tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Hey buddy, there haven't really been any methods, its in the form controls its a GUI controller so there is no code. All I have is my form which is a series of check boxes buttons and text boxes titles and labels and when I set the anchro properties as suggested below they bleed into each other with no boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Each control has the properties `VerticleAnchor` and `HorizontalAnchor`.

These can be left right or both (top or bottom for verticle) and if it is `left` and `top` (default) they stay those distances from the top and left sides. Changing them to `right` and `bottom` keep their distances from the right and bottom. `Both` resizes the control to have the same spacing from both as the form resizes.

Also double chack that the `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` are `true` to allow for them to resize with the form.

Hope that helps!

**Edit:**

Here is some code from my predecessor that does it using the event:

Private Sub Form_Resize()
On Error GoTo Err_Form_Resize

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmFMEA_PartA").IsLoaded Then

    Dim DatasheetW As Double
    Dim DatasheetH As Double
    Dim FormW As Double
    Dim FormH As Double

    DatasheetW = Me.frmFMEA_PartB_Subform.width
    FormW = Me.WindowWidth

    DatasheetH = Me.frmFMEA_PartB_Subform.Height
    FormH = Me.WindowHeight
    'MsgBox FormH
    'MsgBox DatasheetH

    Me.frmFMEA_PartB_Subform.width = IIf(FormW - 360 > 0, FormW - 360, 1) '390
    Me.frmFMEA_PartB_Subform.Height = IIf(FormH - 3405 > 0, FormH - 3405, 1) '3195

    Me.text.Left = IIf(FormW - 2340 > 0, FormW - 2340, 1)
    Me.text_Logo.Left = IIf(FormW - 2340 > 0, FormW - 2340, 1)

End If

Exit_Form_Resize:
    Exit Sub

Err_Form_Resize:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Form_Resize
End Sub
```

as you can see its a lot of math, trial, and error so I try to do it using the form level properties but maybe this will spart some ideas.

Comment: Hey, First and foremost thanks so much for the quick answer, hoewver this did not solve my problem.  Now when I expand the fields begin overlapping each other and getting real nasty. becomes the electronic equivalent of mush

Comment: If you want to get real picky there is an on resize event I think and you can change control positions and widths based on that. I have never done it but that might be the next thing to look into

Comment: I don'[t know, I'm having trouble they are all expanding into each other and there is nothing stopping them from overlapping all ove rthe place.

Comment: Check out my edit, its a different way to approach it using raww code rather than anchors.